# Mobile access to the project published in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, mobile, publish

I published the project I wrote with asp.net core in my IIS computer
I wanted you to guide me on how to access that project published on IIS via my mobile phone.

Comment: I think that all you need is create a firewall rule to allow http or https traffic and access your IIS site with the local address of your computer

Comment: Discussions without site bindings in context are less helpful to others, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your IIS computer and your mobile should be on the same network. For example, connect to the same Wifi router.

In your IIS machine run `ipconfig` in `cmd` to get to know the machine IP.
Now you can use that IP and HTTP (not HTTPS) for simplicity to open the site on mobile device.

[image]